# QGIS buttons are huge

Tags: qgis, windows

I've got a new laptop with a high dpi and resolution display and the buttons in QGIS are huge.
I'm not using the display since I connected two external screens.
QGIS 3.28.3 and Windows 10.
[image]

I belive I have tried all different compability settings for qgis-bin.exe, and Windows display settings.

Anyone who knows how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try reducing the icon size in the general-tab of the QGIS settings.

[image]